# How to debug unresponsive async NSURLConnection

Tags: asynchronous, nsurlconnection, freeze

and by unresponsive I mean that after the first three successful connections, the fourth connection is initiated and nothing happens, no crashes, no delegate functions called, no data is sent out (according to wireshark)... it just sits there?!

I've been beating my head against this for a day and half...
iOS 4.3.3
latest xCode, happens the same way on a real device as in the simulator.
I've read all the NSURLConnection posts in the Developer Forums... I'm at a loss.

From my application delegate, I kick off an async NSURLConnection according to Apple docs, using the App Delegate as the delegate for the NSURLConnection.

From my applicationDidFinishLaunching... I trigger the initial two queries which successfully return XML that I then pass off to a OperationQueue to be parsed.
I can even loop, repeating these queries with no issues, repeated them 10 times and worked just fine.

The next series of five queries are triggered via user input. The first query runs successfully and returns the correct response, then the next query is created and when used to create a NSURLConnection (just like all the others), just sits there.?!

The normal delegate calls I see on all the other queries are never seen.
Nothing goes over the wire according to Wireshark?
I've reordered the queries and regardless of the query, after the first one the next one fails (fails as in does nothing, no errors or aborts, just sits there)

It's obviously in my code, but I am blind to it.

So what other tools can I use to debug the async NSURLConnection...  how can I tell what it's doing? if at all.

Any suggestions for debugging a NSURLConnection or other ways accomplish doing the same thing a NSURLConnection does??

Thanks for any help you can offer...

Comment: ... maybe post some code here?

Comment: there's a ton of it that's why I'm just looking for tips on how to further debug the NSURLConnection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK tracked it down...
I was watching the stack dump in each thread as I was about to kick off each NSURLConnection, the first three were all in the main thread as expected... the fourth one ended up in a new thread?!  In one of my NSOperation thread?!?!
As it turns out I inadvertently added logic(?) that started one my NSURLConnection in the last NSOperation call to didFinishParsing:  so the NSURLConnection was async started and then the NSOperation terminated...  >.<

So I'll move the NSURLConnection out of the didFinishParsing and it should stay in the main loop and I should be good!

Comment: Awesome! I was banging my head against this.  The logic that was subsequently making my HTTP call was being kicked off from a different thread.  Once I added execute on main thread my HTTP requests worked again.  This had me confused because it WAS working until i moved some code around.  So for a while I was going insane :)